# Unable to access boot menu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, uefi

I've been having a difficult time trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop due to a silly mistake I made earlier. During the setup process, I installed the boot loader to `/dev/sda8` instead of `/dev/sda` and I've been running into trouble ever since.

Right now, I am unable to access the F2 and F12 menus when I boot up, and I am also unable to boot from a CD or other media to re-install Ubuntu. I tried opening Wubi and it added an option inside the Windows boot loader to boot from a disk, which doesn't work because I opened Wubi on a flash drive.

I have also tried holding shift to enter Windows' boot menu and from there, I should see an option that allows me to boot from a disk but there is none.

I currently have a mini iso version of Ubuntu sitting on a DVD (the full version wouldn't fit) and I am unable to boot from it to re-do my botched installation.

Edit: This computer is a Dell laptop running win8, so instead of BIOS, it has UEFI.

Edit 2: Currently updating drivers, Dell had an update for the BIOS. e: It went surprisingly quickly.

Comment: no idea but i'm curious, did it used to say press F2 or press F12, but now not?  also you should know that you can hold the key rather than tap it, but probably won't help.   And tihs probably won't help but i guess you could try holding the power button to make sure it is shutting down fully.. or try removing the battery too. I've heard of win8 not shutting down completely and people think they then can't access the boot menu.. but probably won't help in your case. Maybe it's possible to downgrade the UEFI

Comment: I did hear about the win8 shutdown thing but I had already changed that setting. Upgrading the BIOS is what triggered some sort of fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you are savvy enough to do it, I would consider removing the CMOS battery from the motherboard and re-seating. You would be amazed at how many problems that solves.

Comment: It's a dell laptop, so it's going to be pretty difficult to re-seat. I was hoping for less hardware-based solutions, but if it comes to that, I will try it out. Thanks

Comment: Scratch what I said. You could flash the bios using a USB drive. That should do the trick, and there is no hardware maintenance whatsoever.

Comment: I probably should have said that this laptop runs windows 8, and has UEFI instead of BIOS, so it's a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: No problem, at least you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

A simple BIOS update from Dell did the trick, I'm able to access both menus now and am fixing my Ubuntu install right now.

Comment: you said yourself it's a UEFI so why do you keep saying BIOS?